# Concatenate more than 2 files wav in java

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Concatenating WAV files in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8785370/concatenating-wav-files-in-java)

What's the simplest way to concatenate more than two WAV files in Java?

Comment: @assylias : thank you for your answer this is what i want exactly but when i run it i can listen the audio very well !!!! the song is changed , i dont khnow why???

Comment: @user1295121 neither do I. You could post a new question, with more details about what you are doing (show relevant code) and the problems you encounter. Someone might be able to help.

Answer (score 2):

If you're asking about concatenating **more** than two, I'll assume that you already have a way to concatenate exactly two.

In which case you can concatenate multiple files together by simply concatenating each file in turn to the rolling total.  Something like this (for four files):

```
concatenate(concatenate(concatenate(wav1, wav2), wav3), wav4);
```

Comment: But my task is not simple as you think

Comment: i want to concatenate and write the new file audio .wave

i did the concatenation beetween two files and it worked very well
but when i tried to do more than 2 , i am blocked

Comment: i want to publish my code to see what i did but i cant nowi will try later

Comment: i am refernced to this page https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2155130

Comment: @user1295121 - If your task isn't as simple as I think, then perhaps you should have explained the complexities in your question.  How else did you expect people would take them into account?